# Alternate Level order traversal in binary tree

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to do level order traversal for binary tree. But the trick is instead of normal level order traversal, I want to do it alternatively. For e.g.

[image]

**Normal Level order traversal : `1 2 3 4 5`**

What I am looking for is lets say we print the root. Now for every even level I want to go anti-clockwise and for every odd level I would go clockwize:

**For this kind of traversal the output should be: `1 2 3 4 5`**

This is what I tried so far, but this produces a slightly different output than what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key


    # Function to  print level order traversal of tree
    def printLevelOrder(root):
        h = height(root)
        for i in range(1, h+1):     
           printGivenLevel(root, i)

    def printGivenLevel(root , level):
        if root is None:
           return
        if level == 1:
           print(root.val)
        elif level > 1 and level%2 == 0:
             #print("level",level)
             printGivenLevel(root.right , level-1)
             printGivenLevel(root.left , level-1)

        else:
           #print("level",level)
            printGivenLevel(root.left, level-1)
            printGivenLevel(root.right , level-1)


    def height(node):
        if node is None:
           return 0
        else :
        # Compute the height of each subtree 
           lheight = height(node.left)
           rheight = height(node.right)

           #Use the larger one
           if lheight > rheight :
              return lheight+1
           else:
              return rheight+1

# Driver code
root = Node(1)
root.left      = Node(2)
root.right     = Node(3)
root.left.left  = Node(4)
root.left.right  = Node(5)
root.right.left  = Node(6)
root.right.right  = Node(7)
root.left.left.left  = Node(8)
root.left.left.right  = Node(9)
root.right.left.left  = Node(10)
root.right.right.right  = Node(11)


print ("Level order traversal of binary tree is -")
printLevelOrder(root)
```

This program produces this output:

`1 3 2 5 4 7 6 10 11 9 8`

What I need:

`1 2 3 7 6 5 4 8 9 10 11`.

Comment: "For this kind of traversal the output should be: `1 2 3 4 5`", this is the same as the normal traversal - is this what you meant?

Comment: No. By "this kind of the traversal" I meant the alternate traversal. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change function printGivenLevel() like this

```
def printGivenLevel(root , levelrem, level):                                    
    if root is None:                                                            
       return                                                                   
    if levelrem == 1:                                                           
       print(root.val)                                                          
    elif level > 1 and level%2 == 0:                                            
         printGivenLevel(root.left , levelrem-1, level)    # you had root.right                      
         printGivenLevel(root.right , levelrem-1, level)   # you had root.left                       

    else:                                                                       
        printGivenLevel(root.right, levelrem-1, level)     # you had root.left                    
        printGivenLevel(root.left , levelrem-1, level)     # you had root.right
```

Here levelrem variable denotes when to print a leaf and level denotes actual level of the leaf. call printGivenLevel() as `printGivenLevel(root, i, i)`

**ALSO NOTE** Indentation is very important in python. The code you have given in the question does not work as it is. One have to understand that class Node only have the **init()** method.

Comment: Okay I will keep this indention rule in mind. Can you please explain what I did wrong and why you keep an extra `level` in the function. I understand the `root.left` and `root .right` part but didn't quite get the purpose of the extra variable

Comment: In your code, level keeps changing during recursive calls. So there was no way of knowing which level was even and which level was odd. Now level maintains that information even between recursion calls and levelrem is just for denoting when to terminate the recursion and print the given level.